# AJAX Post from same domain to a wordpress page

Tags: ajax, page-template

I am trying to create an ajax post listener to a wordpress page in a domain (let's just say http://example.com). Another web app in the same domain (http://example.com) exists and a user sends ajax posts from there.

I have implemented a simple page:

```
<?php
get_header();
?>
<h3>Listener</h3>
<div id="listener1">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    console.log("Into WPTOASTER");
    $.ajaxSetup({
        success: function() {
            console.log("trapped?");
        }
    });
});
</script>
<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

that is located to http://example.com/listener .

In the same server, I have an http://example.com/zzz.php which has the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.3'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="aaaa">
<input type="hidden" name="aaa" value="111">
<button type="button" id="salty">CLICK AND SUBMIT</button>
</form>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(document).on("click","#salty",function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        $.post('http://example.com/listener',{"name":"john","lastname":"smith"},function(data){
            console.log("check if sent.");
        });
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I use zzz.php to send ajax requests to listener I get a 404 error. The operation would be a simple notification once the php is received. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

First, WordPress has a built-in way to handle AJAX requests, you should [read this page](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) and use that method instead.

The issue with your method is that you're `POST`ing the `name` var. [`name` is a WordPress query var](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters), and is causing WordPress to query for a page with slug `John`. Always prefix your vars with a unique string to avoid these problems.

Comment: Ok this was a bad example of data payload (They are not my full data). What I really want for the listener template page to do is actually "listen" to POST requests. I will be using later woocommerce to send new orders there instead of an email, without the need to refresh (this page would be protected or ideally it would be transferred to a panel in the admin area).

Comment: If not AJAX, then use the [`admin_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_post_(action)) action to handle them. You're running a needless query to serve those requests with a page.

Comment: Excuse me, but read again the requirement, *without the need to refresh*. It's something similar to the woocommerce desktop notifications plugin in codecanyon only I want to implement something different on top of it.

Comment: So what's the issue? Did you read the page about how to use AJAX with WordPress? Do that. That's what the plugin you're trying to replicate does.

Comment: No it doesn't. The plugin polls for post ajax requests all the admin area and then displays using html5 notification the url of the sender of a specific message (the new order one). I'm stuck on the post ajax polling. That's what I am asking.

Comment: Maybe you want the Heartbeat API? Your code doesn't make much sense to me so I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, sorry.

Comment: Unfortunately websockets using Ratchet is the most ideal way. Now other problems emerged, but in my local environment its been working.

Comment: I am on the same boat as Milo, your code doesn't make much sense to me.
To try to understand, the page being used by the user is zzz.php, correct ? and that is the page the user will interact with ( #salty ), and get feedback without any refresh, correct ?
If so, I dont understand why the wordpress ajax API is not suitable for you.
The ajax url should point to admin-ajax.php.
The ajax request should have an action defined.
then, in your functions.php, register the handler with the hook wp_ajax_priv_{your action name}
Define your handler in functions.php as well